# dig: "Transfer failed."

Tags: domain-name-system, dig, dns-zone

INPUT:

```
dig +multiline google.com axfr
```

OUTPUT:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-RedHat-9.7.3-1.fc14 <<>> +multiline google.com axfr
;; global options: +cmd
; Transfer failed.
```

What am I missing?
Regarding: [DNS Lookup to Bind config file](https://serverfault.com/questions/241921/dns-lookup-to-bind-config-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dig against your own nameservers when you attempt a zone transfer.  This needs to be specifically permitted by the `allow-transfer` directive.  Zone transfers should be disabled by default to protect the zone from prying eyes and from the possibility of a denial of service attack.

Answer (score 6):

Google is not going to let you do a zone transfer from them.

Zone transfer permissions are in most cases granted only to a very specific subset of other hosts, and almost never to the public at large.

Comment: Will help explain why zone transfers are restricted http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/dns/securing-dns-zone-transfer_868